# How to efficiently make a text-based menu?

Tags: python

I am currently making a program with a text based menu, and I was wondering if there was anyway to avoid an excessive amount of if-statements while keeping it object oriented. I thought of something like this:

```
class Options:
    def displayOptions():
        #display user options
    def option1():
        #do option 1
    def option2():
        #do option 2 
    def option3():
        #do option 3 and so on

class Menu(Options):
    options = {1: option1(), 2: option2(), 3: option3()} #and so on 
    def promptUser():
        #prompts user to make a choice
    def printHeader():
        #prints header
    def handleInput():
        #checks if input is valid
    def begin():
        #initialize menu
```

Would something like this be convoluted? Is the Options class pointless? I'm pretty new to OOP and I was wondering how this would most efficiently be done.

Comment: Something like this could certainly work, sometimes the abstraction isn’t really worth it. I think you would have write a bit more before anyone could form an informed opinion.

Comment: You're on the right track with the `options` dictionary.  However, the problem is `option1` et al don't exist in that scope.  So, that code won't run.  Let me give this some thought.

Comment: I suggest looking at the built-in [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but it gets the job done.

```py
class Options:
    def doOption(self, opt):
        option = f'option{opt}'
        func = type(self).__dict__.get(option)
        if hasattr(func, '__call__'):
            return func(self)

        raise ValueError(f'Unsupported option: {opt}')

class Menu(Options):
    def option1(self):
        print('Foo!')

    def option2(self):
        print('Bar!')

    def optionbang(self):
        print('Bang!')

menu = Menu()
menu.doOption(1) # Foo!
menu.doOption(2) # Bar!
menu.doOption('bang') # Bang!
```

What this does is look through the the class' properties and try to find a function (i.e., `hasattr(func, '__call__')`) with the right name.  The nice thing is that the logic doesn't even require `opt` to be an integer.

That being said, if this is your only use case, then I agree with @GradyPlayer in the comments that the abstraction probably isn't worth it.

Comment: Wow! This was an interesting point of view. At this point, is there a purpose of creating an options class? Should you keep the class just for organization purposes or is it better to just turn doOption() into a method of menu?

Comment: If this is your only use case, you can just squash this into one class.

Comment: Please excuse my questions, but what are some examples of other use cases?

Comment: No problem at all.  Imagine that you had multiple menus in your program each with different options.  In that case, you would want to use the `Options` base class as shown above and then subclass for each different set of options.  However, if you only have one set of options, running through them via `if`/`elif` is probably the best way to go.  No need to overcomplicate things for a simple use case.

Answer (score -3):

!Py3 code!

```
    b=input('>')

    if b == '1':
    print("")

    if b == '2':

        print("")

     if b == '2':
        print("")

       if b == '3':
        print("")

      else
        Print('please select a valid option. thanks!')
       b=input('>')

     if b == '1':
         print("")

      if b == '2':
         print("")

     if b == '3':
        print("")

    if b == '3':
         print("")

       else
        print('please select a valid option. thanks!')
      b=input('>')

    if b == '1':
       print("")

    if b == '2':
       print("")

    if b == '3':
        print("")
```

This is **python.** What it does is it starts, and u have 3 options
1 ...
2 ...
3 ...
If you don't select a valid option, u have 2 more chances.
Use

```
    Print('*')
```

to show another text.
*: what u want it to say

To add 1 option, use

```
    If b == '*1':
     Print('*2')
```

*1: the option numeral/word u want
*2: the word(s) u want it to say when it is selected.

Comment: Repeating the same code multiple times is terrible practice. And your indentation is completely off.